# AngularJs: HTTP POST with no request params

Tags: angularjs, json, http-post, angular-http

I'm trying to submit a login form to a rest Api using $http service for send the request, but when I submit the form, no request params are passed to. This is my code:

```
controller.formData = {
username :  $scope.formData.username,
password :  $scope.formData.password,
};
$http({
  method  : 'POST',
  url     : 'http://localhost:8080/multe-web/signin',
  data    : controller.formData,  
  headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }  
 })
.success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
 });
```

[image]

Comment: You need to call $http using a function, it wont be called automatically.

Comment: It's already inside a function called on submit the form. This is not the problem.

Comment: Please mention that in question, also there is no html code in the question too.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :-

```
   controller.formData = {
                           username: $scope.formData.username,
                           password: $scope.formData.password,
                          }

    sendRequest(controller.formData).success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    })


    function sendRequest(data) {

      var sendRequest = $http.post("http://localhost:8080/multe-web/signin", data);
      return sendRequest;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.post(
    authUrl+'/things',
    $.param(requestData),
    {
        headers:
        {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    }
)
.success(function(data, status){

    deffered.resolve(data, status);
}).error(function(data,status){

});
```

Refer this.

Comment: I can't use Jquery and also my api rest accept only application/json.

Answer (score 0):

*HTML*:

```
<form id="your_form" name='your_form' ng-submit="check.submit(your_form)">
   <input type="password" ng-model='passValue'>
   <input type="text" ng-model='userNameValue'>
</form>
```

*Controllers.js*:

```
 $scope.check = {
    submit : function() {
        var data;
        data = {
           'username' :  $scope.userNameValue,
           'password' :  $scope.passValue,
        };
        var request = $http({
            method:  'POST',
            url:     'http://localhost:8080/multe-web/signin',
            data:    data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
        request.then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        request.catch(function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        })
    }
};
```

Comment: updated, maybe it helps. You have to choose right data via ng-model.